# wc -l is NOT counting last of the file if it does not have end of line character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to count all lines of an unix file. The file has 3 lines but `wc -l` gives only 2 count.

I understand that it is not counting last line because it does not have end of line character

Could any one please tell me how to count that line as well ?

Comment: Just for information: [the POSIX definition of a line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) is _A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is better to have all lines ending with EOL `\n` in Unix files. You can do:

```
{ cat file; echo ''; } | wc -l
```

Or this awk:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

Comment: You can always do `echo -n '' >> file` on your local filesystem

Comment: I did add it but still NOT working. `echo -n '' >> file` not adding end of line char !!

Comment: Can you show output of `tail -1 file | od -cx` after doing `echo -n '' >> file`

Comment: Another way to count is: `{ cat file; echo ''; } | wc -l`

Comment: `0000000   p   r   m   |   /   e   x   p   o   r   t   /   h   o   m   e
        7270 7c6d 652f 7078 726f 2f74 6f68 656d
0000020   /   d   p   o   t   l   u   r   i   /   p   r   m   /   D   M
        642f 6f70 6c74 7275 2f69 7270 2f6d 4d44
0000040   P   I   -   7   8   5   3   .   p   r   m  \0
        4950 372d 3538 2e33 7270 006d
0000053
`

Comment: Or even `awk 'END{print NR}' file`

Comment: `{ cat file; echo ''; } | wc -l` is working. Thanks;Can you please re post the answer ? so that i will accept !

Comment: @logan: Note that `{ cat file; echo ''; } | wc -l` will give the wrong answer if the file already ends with a `\n`, since it **always** adds an extra line, so the awk-based solutions are better.

Comment: @logan: Did you get wrong output from `awk 'END{print NR}' file`?

Comment: @anubhava : I did not try that. Anyhow i accepted your as "Accepted One" again. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

`grep -c` returns the number of matching lines. Just use an empty string `""` as your matching expression:

```
$ echo -n $'a\nb\nc' > 2or3.txt
$ cat 2or3.txt | wc -l
2
$ grep -c "" 2or3.txt
3
```

Comment: Even without the `-F` flag, the grep solution is measurable faster than the minimal `awk` or `sed` version, and pretty close to `wc -l` itself.

Comment: `rg --fixed-strings --count ''` for `ripgrep`.

Answer (score 7):

This approach will give the correct line count regardless of whether the last line in the file ends with a newline or not.

`awk` will make sure that, in its output, each line it prints ends with a new line character.  Thus, to be sure each line ends in a newline before sending the line to `wc`, use:

```
awk '1' file | wc -l
```

Here, we use the trivial `awk` program that consists solely of the number `1`.  `awk` interprets this cryptic statement to mean "print the line" which it does, being assured that a trailing newline is present.

#### Examples

Let us create a file with three lines, each ending with a newline, and count the lines:

```
$ echo -n $'a\nb\nc\n' >file
$ awk '1' f | wc -l
3
```

The correct number is found.

Now, let's try again with the last new line missing:

```
$ echo -n $'a\nb\nc' >file
$ awk '1' f | wc -l
3
```

This still provides the right number.  `awk` automatically corrects for a missing newline but leaves the file alone if the last newline is present.

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't require modifying the file, and it doesn't change the count if unneeded.

Answer (score 2):

### Respect

I respect the [answer from John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28038773/117471) and would like to expand upon it.

### Line Count function

I find myself comparing line counts A LOT especially from the clipboard, so I have defined a bash function. I'd like to modify it to show the filenames and when passed more than 1 file a total. However, it hasn't been important enough for me to do so far.

```sh
# semicolons used because this is a condensed to 1 line in my ~/.bash_profile
function wcl(){
  if [[ -z "${1:-}" ]]; then
    set -- /dev/stdin "$@";
  fi;
  for f in "$@"; do
    awk 1 "$f" | wc -l;
  done;
}
```

### Counting lines without the function

```sh
# Line count of the file
$ cat file_with_newline    | wc -l
       3

# Line count of the file
$ cat file_without_newline | wc -l
       2

# Line count of the file unchanged by cat
$ cat file_without_newline | cat | wc -l
       2

# Line count of the file changed by awk
$ cat file_without_newline | awk 1 | wc -l
       3

# Line count of the file changed by only the first call to awk
$ cat file_without_newline | awk 1 | awk 1 | awk 1 | wc -l
       3

# Line count of the file unchanged by awk because it ends with a newline character
$ cat file_with_newline    | awk 1 | awk 1 | awk 1 | wc -l
       3
```

### Counting characters (why you don't want to put a wrapper around `wc`)

```
# Character count of the file
$ cat file_with_newline    | wc -c
       6

# Character count of the file unchanged by awk because it ends with a newline character
$ cat file_with_newline    | awk 1 | awk 1 | awk 1 | wc -c
       6

# Character count of the file
$ cat file_without_newline | wc -c
       5

# Character count of the file changed by awk
$ cat file_without_newline | awk 1 | wc -c
       6
```

### Counting lines with the function

```
# Line count function used on stdin
$ cat file_with_newline    | wcl
       3

# Line count function used on stdin
$ cat file_without_newline | wcl
       3

# Line count function used on filenames passed as arguments
$ wcl file_without_newline  file_with_newline
       3
       3
```

Answer (score 0):

'wc -l ' doesn't count the lines of file.
It counts the count of '\n' (newline).

```
from man page of wc

 -l, --lines
              print the newline counts
```

you should use grep -c '^' to get lines count.

```
grep -c '^' filename
```

Comment: This merely appears to repeat information from earlier answers.