# bash-script - don't see last line of file in find command

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs

I wrote script which  shows number of lines in .z format files. But it doesn't count last line if where is not end of line character. how can I fix it?
`

```
todays_day=$(date +%d) 
if ((todays_day==1)); then
  month="$(date --date='1 day ago' +%y%m)"
else
  month="$(date +%y%m)"
fi
for file in $(find ./ -type d -name "$month")
do
    echo "number of lines $(find $file -type f -name "*.z" | xargs zcat | awk 1 | wc -l);source $(find $file -type d );data $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %T")"
     
done
```

`

I looked [wc -l is NOT counting last of the file if it does not have end of line character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038633/wc-l-is-not-counting-last-of-the-file-if-it-does-not-have-end-of-line-character) but it didn't help. I use awk 1 but my script count correct number of line only in 1 file

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: I don't understand this part of the pipeline: ` | xargs zcat | awk 1 | wc -l| wc -l` -- `awk 1` is essentially `cat`, what purpose does it have here? The second `wc -l` is processing the output of the first `wc -l`

Comment: Oh, I see that `awk 1` will add a newline to last line

Comment: But `wc -l | wc -l` seems like it must be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Let's create a minimal example:

```bash
printf '1\n2\n3' > a.dat
printf '4\n5\n6' > b.dat
```

Since these are not compressed, let's see what happens with `xargs cat`

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' *.dat
a.dat
b.dat

$ printf '%s\n' *.dat | xargs cat
1
2
34
5
6⏎

$ printf '%s\n' *.dat | xargs cat | wc -l
4

$ printf '%s\n' *.dat | xargs cat | awk 1 | wc -l
5
```

where `⏎` means "no trailing newline"

We see in the middle `34`. This means that the last line of the first file is concatenated with the first line of the second file.

This means that `xargs zcat` is insufficient to accurately count the "lines" of the compressed files. IMO you'll have to stop using `xargs` and `zcat $file | awk 1 | wc -l` the files one by one.

Note "lines" is in quotes here: a "proper" line must have a line ending character: a newline.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250006/discussion-on-answer-by-glenn-jackman-bash-script-dont-see-last-line-of-file).